# Julia on Colab: need to use ''diffeqpy'' BUT can't Install Julia

Tags: python, installation, julia, google-colaboratory

I need to use "diffeqpy" module which utilize Julia's DifferentialEquations.jl on Python. I'm using Google Colab and in order to be able to import the module I have to install Julia First.

can anyone help how to do so? some links like [this](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/julia-on-google-colab-free-gpu-accelerated-shareable-notebooks/15319) suggested some ways to do the installation. but it doesn't work for me.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Colab team [maintains a notebook that showcases how to install Julia on Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/ageron/julia_notebooks/blob/master/Julia_Colab_Notebook_Template.ipynb). After that is done, `pip install diffeqpy` should be sufficient for receiving a working version of diffeqpy.